# Data Preparation End OF Every Month - Moving Over 12 Months

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, monthcalendar

I have data prep procedure in SQL. I want to have data preparation at the end of every month
 Say I want the procedure run on last day of month e.g. on 31 January 2020 it should prep data from 1 January to 31 January.

So it's kind of moving window over all months of the year. Because I need data for evaluation at the end of each month.

I tried this, however, this does not give automation. Its sort of manual running end of every month

```
select '2020-10-01' as beginDate_AnalysisWindow  
, '2020 -01-31' as endDate_AnalysisWindow 
   into #AnalysisWindow --create temporary table #AnalysisWindow
```

I also tried the following, however, I’m not sure if it does for the whole month or just one day?

```
SELECT START_OF_MONTH_DATE AS beginDate_AnalysisWindow
,END_OF_MONTH_DATE AS endDate_AnalysisWindow
INTO #AnalysisWindow
FROM [dbo].[Date] WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE DATE = DATEADD(dd, - 1,  CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
```

Could someone pls help me/give me some suggestions.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: because that query is product specific.

Comment: What does your end result look like?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the last day of the current month, use `eomonth()`:

```
WHERE DATE = CONVERT(date, EOMONTH(GETDATE()))
```

Note:  This assumes that the `date` column has no time component.  If that is the case:

```
WHERE CONVERT(date, DATE) = CONVERT(date, EOMONTH(GETDATE()))
```

SQL Server will still use an index (if available) even for this type of conversion.

EDIT:

To get the current months data, one method is:

```
WHERE DATE <= CONVERT(date, EOMONTH(GETDATE())) AND
      DATE > CONVERT(date, EOMONTH(GETDATE(), -1))
```

The second argument to `EOMONTH()` is a months offset.

Comment: thanks, v much. does this mean; I will get data from the first day and last day of the month then?

Comment: @JamesTaylor . . . This is just the last day:  "Because I need data for evaluation at the end of each month."

Comment: sorry I should rephrase "I want to have data preparation on last day, but it should be for all days of months (e.g. from 1 - 31: (31 days in case of January))

Answer (score 0):

You can also try:

```
where getdate() <= EOMONTH(GETDATE()) AND
      getdate() > DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH(GETDATE(), -1))
```

Instead of getdate(), you can use your date column.